# Update Images for odoo in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

may I ask you, which format uses Odoo to display images for Products and how to update product images directly into PostgreSQL for Odoo from Python?

I use

```
cursor.execute('select image_medium from product_product where id = 58')
(file_data) = cursor.fetchone()[0]
writeImage(file_data)
conn.commit()
```

and can not open file in any image editor after saving to disk.

Alternatively,

```
data = readImage()
binary = psycopg2.Binary(data)
cursor.execute('update product_product set image_small = %s where id = 57', (binary,))
conn.commit()
```

makes product could not be opened anymore in Odoo.

Any answer greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 methods encodestring() and decodestring()

Eg:

```
img = base64.decodestring(file_data)
writeImage(img)
```